Generación de Laberinto random con C++
hace unos días me pidieron aprender C++, para hacer un algoritmo que genere un Laberinto al alzar y luego lo resuelva, así también, que muestre el camino al punto final. El error que tengo, es que cuando quiero generar el camino al punto final, me marca todo el laberinto en sí con la X.
Esto sería la primera parte del algoritmo, donde generamos un laberinto e imprimimos.
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <stack>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

random_device rd; // se crea un generador de números aleatorios.
mt19937 generadorNumero(rd()); // se inicializa un generador de números aleatorios que viene del rd.

// declaramos las filas, colummnas y el valor ingresado.
int filas, columnas, valorIngresado;

// estructuramos la Celda.
struct Celda
{
    bool celdaVisitada;
    bool paredSuperior;
    bool paredInferior;
    bool paredIzquierda;
    bool paredDerecha;

    // esto es el constructor de la estructura Celda. Inicializamos por default cada uno de las variables.
    Celda() : celdaVisitada(false), paredSuperior(true), paredInferior(true), paredIzquierda(true), paredDerecha(true) {}
};

// definimos un nuevo tipo llamado Laberinto, el tipo Laberinto es un vector de vectores donde va cada celda.
typedef vector<vector<Celda> > Laberinto;

// definimos la funcion pasando como parametro la cantidad de filas de colummnas y los referenciamos respectivamente.
void generarLaberinto (Laberinto &laberinto, int fil, int col, mt19937 &generadorNumero){

    // se marca la celda en la posición [fil][col] como visitada.
    laberinto[fil][col].celdaVisitada = true;

    // se declara un vector de pares de enteros. Cada par representa una dirección.
    vector<pair<int, int> > direcciones;
    
    // se agrega al vector 'direcciones' pares de coordenadas que representan direcciones (x, y) derecha, izquierda, arriba, abajo.
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(1, 0));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(-1, 0));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(0, 1));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(0, -1));

    // mezclamos las direcciones usando un generador de números aleatorios con la funcion shuffle.
    shuffle(direcciones.begin(), direcciones.end(), generadorNumero);

    // el bucle recorre cada elemento en el vector 'direcciones'. 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < direcciones.size(); ++i) {

        // obtenemos la dirección actual y referenciamos "dir".
        const pair<int, int> &dir = direcciones[i]; 
        
        // Calculamos la nueva posición.
        int nuevaFila = fil + dir.first;
        int nuevaColumna = col + dir.second;

        // verificamos si la celda está dentro del limite de Laberinto y si no ha sido visitada, por defecto nos devuelve falso, y con el operador logico le decimos true
        if ((nuevaFila >= 0 && nuevaFila < filas) && (nuevaColumna >= 0 && nuevaColumna < columnas) && (!laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].celdaVisitada)) {

            // eliminamos las paredes entre las celdas actuales
            if (dir.first == 1) {
                laberinto[fil][col].paredInferior = false;
                laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].paredSuperior = false;
            } else if (dir.first == -1) {
                laberinto[fil][col].paredSuperior = false;
                laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].paredInferior = false;
            } else if (dir.second == 1) {
                laberinto[fil][col].paredDerecha = false;
                laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].paredIzquierda = false;
            } else if (dir.second == -1) {
                laberinto[fil][col].paredIzquierda = false;
                laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].paredDerecha = false;
            }

            // llamamos de vuelta a nuestra funcion recursivamente 
            generarLaberinto(laberinto, nuevaFila, nuevaColumna, generadorNumero);
        }
    }
};

// definimos la funcion pasando como parametro el tipo laberinto y lo referenciamos.
void imprimirLaberinto(Laberinto &laberinto) {

    // itera por la cantiad de filas.
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i) {

        // itera por la cantidad de columnas y imprime las paredes superiores.
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
            cout << "+";

            // si la paredSuperior es true imprime "---" y si no espacio vacio
            cout << (laberinto[i][j].paredSuperior ? "---" : "   ");
        }
        cout << "+" << endl;

        // itera por la cantidad de columnas, pero esta vez imprime las paredes izquierdas.
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {

            // si la paredIzquierda es true imprime "|" y si no espacio vacio
            cout << (laberinto[i][j].paredIzquierda ? "|" : " ");
            cout << "   ";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

    // itera por la cantidad de columnas, pero se imprime las paredes inferiores.
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
        cout << "+---";
    }
    cout << "+" << endl;
}

Este es su output:
¡Bienvenido al generador de laberintos!
------------------------------------------------

Ingresa el número de filas: 3
Ingresa el número de colummnas: 3

------------------------------------------------

+---+---+---+
|   |       |
+   +   +---+
|   |       |
+   +---+   +
|           |
+---+---+---+

------------------------------------------------
¡Laberinto generado con exito! 

Las dos primeras funciones funcionan correctamente e imprimen correctamente.
Luego viene la segunda parte donde llamo a las funciones que son resolverLaberinto() e imprimirLaberintoResuelto(), me causan problemas, a la hora de inicializar a esas funciones, lo que sucede es que todos los espacios se asigna la X, me gustaría que solo se marquen el camino a la salida, que seria el punto final, y de los espacios que no tienen salida, se quite esos X. Creo que hay algún problema con la lógica.
Este seria el resto del codigo
void resolverLaberinto(Laberinto &laberinto, int filaActual, int columnaActual) {
    // Marcar la celda como visitada
    laberinto[filaActual][columnaActual].celdaVisitada = true;

    // Vector de direcciones posibles: arriba, abajo, izquierda, derecha
    vector<pair<int, int> > direcciones;
    
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(1, 0));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(-1, 0));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(0, 1));
    direcciones.push_back(make_pair(0, -1));

    // Recorrer las direcciones
    for (size_t i = 0; i < direcciones.size(); ++i) {
        const pair<int, int> &dir = direcciones[i];
        int nuevaFila = filaActual + dir.first;
        int nuevaColumna = columnaActual + dir.second;

        // Verificar si la nueva celda es válida y no ha sido visitada
        if (nuevaFila >= 0 && nuevaFila < laberinto.size() &&
            nuevaColumna >= 0 && nuevaColumna < laberinto[0].size() &&
            !laberinto[nuevaFila][nuevaColumna].celdaVisitada) {
            // Verificar si no hay pared entre las celdas
            if (dir.first == -1 && !laberinto[filaActual][columnaActual].paredSuperior) {
                resolverLaberinto(laberinto, nuevaFila, nuevaColumna);
            } else if (dir.first == 1 && !laberinto[filaActual][columnaActual].paredInferior) {
                resolverLaberinto(laberinto, nuevaFila, nuevaColumna);
            } else if (dir.second == -1 && !laberinto[filaActual][columnaActual].paredIzquierda) {
                resolverLaberinto(laberinto, nuevaFila, nuevaColumna);
            } else if (dir.second == 1 && !laberinto[filaActual][columnaActual].paredDerecha) {
                resolverLaberinto(laberinto, nuevaFila, nuevaColumna);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Función para imprimir el laberinto, marcando el camino encontrado durante la resolución
void imprimirLaberintoResuelto(Laberinto &laberinto) {
    // Itera por las filas del laberinto
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; ++i) {
        // Imprime las paredes superiores
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
            cout << "+";
            cout << (laberinto[i][j].paredSuperior ? "---" : "   ");
        }
        cout << "+" << endl;

        // Imprime las paredes izquierdas y el contenido de las celdas
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
            cout << (laberinto[i][j].paredIzquierda ? "|" : " ");

            // Si la celda ha sido visitada, imprime un símbolo para marcar el camino
            if (laberinto[i][j].celdaVisitada) {
                cout << " X ";
            } else {
                cout << "   ";
            }
        }
        // Imprime la pared derecha de la última columna
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }

    // Imprime las paredes inferiores
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
        cout << "+---";
    }
    cout << "+" << endl;
}


int main () {

    // imprimimos las instrucciones y pedimos los datos al usuario.
    cout << "\n¡Bienvenido al generador de laberintos!" <<endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    cout << "Ingresa el número de filas: ";
    cin >> filas;
    cout << "Ingresa el número de colummnas: " ;
    cin >> columnas;

    cout << "\n------------------------------------------------\n" << endl;

    // llamamos a nuestro tipo Laberinto y le nombramos como laberinto, cargamos las filas del primer vector, luego dentro de ese vector cargamos las columnas.
    Laberinto laberinto(filas, vector<Celda>(columnas));

    // lLamamos a la funcion de generar el Laberinto.
    generarLaberinto(laberinto, 0, 0, generadorNumero);

    // aca llamamos a nuestra funcion donde imprimimos el laberinto
    imprimirLaberinto(laberinto);


    // mas intrucciones
    cout << "\n------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "¡Laberinto generado con exito! \n" <<endl;

    // aqui solicitamos al usuario el siguiente paso, si quiere ver el Laberinto resuelto o dejar de jugar.
    cout << "¿Le gustaria ver el laberinto resuelto, o lo resuelves usted mismo?"<< endl;

    cout << "Marque 1 (Sí) o marque cualquier otro número (No)" <<endl;
    cin >> valorIngresado;

    // si el usuario ingresa 1, le imprime el Laberinto resuelto.
    if ( valorIngresado == 1 ) {
         resolverLaberinto(laberinto, 0, 0);
         imprimirLaberintoResuelto(laberinto);

    } else {
        cout << "¡Gracias por jugar!";
    }
}; ```

y este es su respectivo output

```¿Le gustaria ver el laberinto resuelto, o lo resuelves usted mismo?
Marque 1 (Sí) o marque cualquier otro número (No)
1
+---+---+---+
| X | X   X |
+   +   +---+
| X | X   X |
+   +---+   +
| X   X   X |
+---+---+---+ ```

Ahí se puede notar como en todas las posiciones de las filas y columnas, se imprime con la X.


Alguien me podría ayudar a mejorar esa lógica. Desde ya, muchas gracias !!


El problema radica en la condición utilizada para imprimir la 'X':
if (laberinto[i][j].celdaVisitada) {
    cout << " X ";
} else {
    cout << "   ";
}

Esta condición imprime una 'X' en cualquier celda que haya sido marcada como visitada durante la generación del laberinto (generarLaberinto), no solo en las celdas que forman el camino encontrado por la función resolverLaberinto.
Para corregir el error, se debe modificar la condición para imprimir la 'X' solo en las celdas que forman el camino. Una forma de hacerlo es agregar una variable o estructura de datos que almacene las celdas que forman el camino durante la ejecución de resolverLaberinto. Luego, en imprimirLaberintoResuelto, se puede verificar si la celda actual está presente en esa estructura de datos antes de imprimir la 'X'.
